# JRE installation using webupd8 PPA, possible ? how does it harm if I use JDK when JRE is enough for me?

Tags: 12.04, installation, server

Could I install only JRE using webupd8 PPA. I think this ppa provides JDK. But I just need JRE. How does it harm if I use JDK when JRE is enough for my webserver?

Another thing if I install a package using a PPA or `apt-get install` utility would I automatically be receiving updates/ upcomning releases whenever I do `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/) PPA you will be installing the official , publicly available Java SE JDK which also contains the JRE as a part of that download. If your wish is only to install the JRE and not the JDK, then you can choose to use the manual method of obtaining the latest JRE from Oracle's website, and then finding the [Easy Linux Tips Project page](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java#TOC-HOW-TO-FOR-64-BIT-UBUNTU) and following the method there.

You will not be harmed using the JDK, and the PPA may be a much better option for you  For one thing, the scripts to make the java defaults proper in the PPA are much better for you depending on what you use within java, and take effect on all properties versus the manual method (IMHO).

The PPA can only update when updates are made in the PPA itself. The manual method requires your own intervention in order to work.  Do hope that helps.